# CultureInfo: Compare including parent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, localization

I was wondering if there was an easy solution to this problem. We have a database with some strings in different languages. They have a language code (eg: `"en"`, `"en-us"`, ...) and a value. I want to match the closest language that the user has.

For example, I have the following information in a database:

```
en-GB = Boot
en = Trunk
nl = Kofferbak
de = Kofferraum
```

I want to match `"en-US"` (from user) with `"en"` (in database), `"en-GB"` with `"en-GB"`, `"nl-NL"` and `nl-BE` with `nl`, and so on.

I'm already using `CultureInfo`, but it doesn't seems like there is a method that does this. I can check the parent of a culture, but I'm hoping that there is a simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no build-in solution to this problem. So, I've made a solution to this problem myself with an extension-method:

```
public static class CultureInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool MatchesWith(this CultureInfo cultureInfo, CultureInfo matchCandidate)
    {
        if (cultureInfo == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return cultureInfo.Equals(matchCandidate) || cultureInfo.Parent.MatchesWith(matchCandidate);
    }
}
```

Sharing this with other people that are going to have this problem, since there are not many topics online about this.

Comment: With your solution :

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.MatchesWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

returns false where it should return true right ?

Comment: In my case it's not needed but you are right: That is unexpected behaviour.